# How to navigate one step back in history in current tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension. On the extenions page I have a button. When pressing this button I want to navigate one step back in history in **the current open tab** so I want this button to behave like the backbutton. I've seen some answers here on SO but no one seems to work for me.
How to do this?

**Update**

I have the following mainfest.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webNavigation",
    "history",
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

and the javascript file.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var btn = document.getElementById('btnRestart');
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log('inside click');
    history.back();
    console.log('after back');
  }, false);
});
```

Comment: what did you try and failed to prevent post similar trials ?

Comment: I've tried history.back() but I can't get it to work. See my updated question.

Comment: You're doing `history.back()` on the popup page. See [extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) and use [Content script injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi).

Comment: Thank you, as I suspect I was doing the call on the popup-page. I tried to stress that in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't leave comments yet but i got an extension to take me back by using the method shown here https://gist.github.com/greatghoul/8120275 of course changing alert() with window.history.back() if it doesn't work at first reopen your chrome.

Comment: That's gonna be flagged as a low-quality answer. You should post the code instead of the link but don't forget to check the existing questions for duplicates in which case flag this question as a duplicate.