# How can I navigate back in the history of the current editor tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cannot find a way to navigate back. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> doesn't make it (I'm on Ubuntu). Instead of going back in the history of the current tab it switches to a tab where I was. That's not what I need.

Sorry for repeating this question as there is already a question on this matter [How to navigate one step back in history in current tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370606/how-to-navigate-one-step-back-in-history-in-current-tab) but it's unanswered and stale and outdated.

Comment: this isn't a duplicate of the post you linked. that other one isn't even about VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"workbench.editor.navigationScope": "editor"
```

The setting's description:

> Controls the scope of history navigation in editors for commands such as 'Go Back' and 'Go Forward'.
>
> `editor`: Navigate only in the active editor.

For your reference / learning purposes, I googled "`github vscode issues navigate back in within current editor`", and got [Have a history per editor for in-editor navigation #36634](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/36634) as my top-third search result, where that setting is mentioned in the completion of the issue ticket [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/36634#issuecomment-1037920173) by Benjamin Pasero.